Projective bundle formula for Connective $K$-theory
I know how to prove that for every vector bundle $E \rightarrow X$ of degree $d$ we have:
$$K^{*}\mathbb{P}(E) = K^{*}X[h]/(\lambda_{-1}[E](h)),$$ where $\lambda_{-1}[E](h) = \sum_{i = 0}^{d}(-1^{i})[\Lambda^iE]h^i \in K^{0}X[h]$, with $h \in K^{0}\mathbb{P}(E)$, the class of the hyperplane bundle, playing the usual role of an indeterminate subject to the relation $\lambda_{-1}[E]$ on the right.
Does any one know an analogous result for $CK^{*}\mathbb{P}(E)$ in Connective $K$-theory, and a reference for the proof?
I have been looking for a reference with an analogous result and proof, but I have not been able to find it.
Thanks in advance for any assistance!
